# Shell Scripting to compare the value of current iteration with that of the previous iteration

Tags: bash, shell, microservices, amazon-ecs

I have an infinite loop which uses aws cli to get the microservice names, it's parameters like desired tasks,number of running task etc for an environment.

There are 100's of microservices running in an environment. I have a requirement to compare the value of aws ecs metric running task for a particular microservice in the current loop and with that of the previous loop.

Say name a microservice X has the metric running task 5. As it is an infinite loop, after some time, again the loop come for the microservice X. Now, let's assume the value of running task is 4. I want to compare the running task for currnet loop, which is 4 with the value of the running task for the previous run, which is 5.

Comment: This is hard to answer without seeing what you have so far, or what the input exactly looks like, or what you want to do with the result of your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking a generic question of how to keep a previous value around so it can be compared to the current value, just store it in a variable.  You can use the following as a starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash

previousValue=0

while read v; do
  echo "Previous value=${previousValue}; Current value=${v}"
  previousValue=${v}
done

exit 0
```

If the above script is called testval.sh.  And you have an input file called test.in with the following values:

```
2
1
4
6
3
0
5
```

Then running

```
./testval.sh <test.in
```

will generate the following output:

```
Previous value=0; Current value=2
Previous value=2; Current value=1
Previous value=1; Current value=4
Previous value=4; Current value=6
Previous value=6; Current value=3
Previous value=3; Current value=0
Previous value=0; Current value=5
```

If the skeleton script works for you, feel free to modify it for however you need to do comparisons.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your input looks exactly, but something like this might be useful for you :

### The script

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A app_stats

while read app tasks
do
  if [[ ${app_stats[$app]} -ne $tasks &&  ! -z ${app_stats[$app]} ]]
  then
    echo "Number of tasks for $app has changed from ${app_stats[$app]} to $tasks"
    app_stats[$app]=$tasks
  else
    app_stats[$app]=$tasks
  fi
done <<< "$( cat input.txt)"
```

### The input

```
App1 2
App2 5
App3 6
App1 6
```

### The output

```
Number of tasks for App1 has changed from 2 to 6
```

Regards!